# line building up animation for input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

Here is my fiddle [**link**](http://jsfiddle.net/v0a5p9yv/59/).

```
jQuery('input').focusin(function(){
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('input').addClass('animatedBottomBorder');
  }, 150);
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('input').addClass('animatedLeftBorder');
  }, 300);
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('input').addClass('animatedTopBorder');
  }, 450);
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('input').addClass('animatedRightBorder');
  }, 600);
});
jQuery('input').focusout(function(){
    jQuery('.searchTextField').removeClass('animatedBottomBorder');
    jQuery('.searchTextField').removeClass('animatedLeftBorder');
    jQuery('.searchTextField').removeClass('animatedTopBorder');
    jQuery('.searchTextField').removeClass('animatedRightBorder');
});
```

In focusin event, borders start to fadein and in focusout event borders disappear.

But the line should look like building up while moving and quite fast. Now it loads in a fade in motion but I want it to be in a moving motion.

Comment: You want the animation to be fast while clicking in and out?

Comment: yes I want it fast, but the main issue is that I want to change fade animation to moving animation, like the line builds up? @DebakantMohanty

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use css3 animations instead? Le: with key frame animation

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code:

```
jQuery('input').focusin(function(){
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('input').css({"border-right-color": 'blue'}).animate({
        borderWidth: 4
    }, 500, 'swing');
  }, 150);
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('input').css({"border-bottom-color": 'green'}).animate({
        borderWidth: 4
    }, 500, 'swing');
  }, 300);
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('input').css({"border-left-color": 'black'}).animate({
        borderWidth: 4
    }, 500, 'swing');
  }, 450);
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('input').css({"border-top-color": 'red'}).animate({
        borderWidth: 4
    }, 500, 'swing');
  }, 600);
});
```

Hope this will help!!

Comment: Thanks for the code. But it is again in fade mode, I want it like the border line fills with white color and that will create the effect of building line. Any ideas? @Debakant Mohanty